# Java create directory using File for Unix / Windows

Tags: java, unix, java-io

I need to create a directory on unix machine. I think the below code will work fine on **unix machine** but fails while testing it on local windows machine. Where does this directory get created on my local machine ?

```
String xmlDir = "/home/data/logs"
File xmlDirectory = new File(xmlDir); 
xmlDirectory.mkdir();
```

I tried below directory path and it worked fine on windows machine. But i had to use the **mkdirs()** instead of **mkdir()** method which needs to be used for unix directory creation?

```
String xmlDir = "C:\\home\\data\\logs"
File xmlDirectory = new File(xmlDir); 
xmlDirectory.mkdirs();
```

How can I make it work locally as well as n unix machine ? Is there a better way for File and Directory creation ?

--Thanks--

Comment: Does the first approach work when you only have `/home/` and no `data` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `System` `user.home` property which will return the user's home directory in a system independent manner, for example...

```
 File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

`mkdir` will only create the last element in the path, where as `mkdirs` will create all the elements that do not exist. Using `mkdirs` is probably a slightly better idea as it ensures (where permissions allow) that all elements in the path will be created if they do not exist

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it worked when I used mkdirs for "/home/data/logs" in windows. It created the above folders in C drive. Not sure of why it created in C drive and not the Users directory which the user home directory. Thanks.

Comment: This will be based on where the application was run from.  `/home/data/logs` say, got to the root of the current drive and make these directories.  As stated, it would be better to use the `user.home` property as this will return you the user home directory, then you can append the path you wan to it - IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You have already hit on the answer:  Just use `mkdirs()`.  It is not platform dependent.  However, if you include platform dependent nomenclature, then you'll run into trouble when moving the code from one environment to another.  Just be sure to use platform independent code, or at the very least, check for the OS before doing so via `System.getProperty("os.name");`